# Errors form my k8s CornJob: Pod errors: Error with exit code 127

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have backend service deployed on a private GKE cluster, and i want to execute this Corn job but everytime i get the following error: `Pod errors: Error with exit code 127`

```
   apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: call-callendar-api-demo
spec:
  
  schedule: "*/15 * * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          nodeSelector:
            env: demo
          containers:
          - name: call-callendar-api-demo
            image: busybox
            command: ["/bin/sh"]
            args: ["-c", 'curl -X POST "curl -X POST "https://x.x.x/api/v1/cal/add_link" -H  "accept: application/json" -d "" >/dev/null 2>&1" -H  "accept: application/json" -d "" >/dev/null 2>&1']
          restartPolicy: Never
```

Any suggestions why this  CornJob that is deployed on the same namespace with my backend service is giving me this error? Also there is no logs in the container :(  btw i have basic auth, could that be a reason?

Edit: Logs from the pod after removing `>/dev/null/`:

```
textPayload: "curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL  

textPayload: "
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (6) Could not resolve host: application
"
```

Comment: [BusyBox](https://busybox.net) doesn't contain a `curl` reimplementation.  Removing the part at the end of the command that suppresses all output might give you some more useful diagnostics.

Comment: @DavidMaze i changed it with image that implement `curl`, now i have `Pod errors: Error with exit code 6`

Comment: Please edit your question to include the actual output from the pod logs (again, removing the `>/dev/null` part of the command).  The error code on its own isn't enough information to suggest any particular change.

Comment: @DavidMaze according this maybe the command is wrongly written?

Comment: yes the command is wrong i have two `curl`

Comment: Exit status `127` basically means `command not found` so definitely there's something wrong with it. _"yes the command is wrong i have two curl"_ - Does it mean you've already managed to resolve it ? If so, please consider sharing what was exactly the issue as an answer.

Comment: @mario thank you for you help, I posted the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command is wrong, and i changed the picture with one that implements `curl` it suppose to look like this.

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: demo
spec:
  
  schedule: "*/15 * * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          nodeSelector:
            env: demo
          containers:
          - name: -demo
            image: curlimages/curl #changed the picture 
            command: ["/bin/sh"]
            args: ["-c", 'curl -X POST "https://x.x.x/api/v1/cal/addy_link" -H  "accept: application/json" -d "" >/dev/null 2>&1']
          restartPolicy: Never
```

It solved my problem.